# I want to search job and salary from employee table but I am getting error like invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select * from emp where job:=:job and sal:=:sal;
```

Comment: I want to get data from prompt without using procedure

Comment: Do you mean using `Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`?

Comment: You are using the PL/SQL assignment operator `:=`; you should be using the equality operator `=`.

Comment: i dont want to compare in querie.I want to ask the data from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual code depends on tool you use. In SQL*Plus, it is the `&`; in SQL Developer or TOAD, that would be a `:`. Also, GUI tools usually don't require enclosing string parameters into single quotes.

Here's a SQL*Plus example:

```
SQL> select * from emp where job = '&job' and sal <= &sal;
Enter value for job: CLERK
Enter value for sal: 1000
old   1: select * from emp where job = '&job' and sal <= &sal
new   1: select * from emp where job = 'CLERK' and sal <= 1000

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800        300         20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30

SQL>
```

Or, a *prettier* way would be to use `ACCEPT` SQL*Plus command:

```
SQL> accept par_job prompt 'Enter job '
Enter job CLERK
SQL> accept par_sal prompt 'Enter salary '
Enter salary 1000
SQL> select * from emp where job = '&par_job' and sal <= &par_sal;
old   1: select * from emp where job = '&par_job' and sal <= &par_sal
new   1: select * from emp where job = 'CLERK' and sal <= 1000

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        800        300         20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30

SQL>
```

SQL Developer would accept the same code as above, or - alternatively -

```
select * from emp where job = :job and sal <= :sal;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works pretty fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive input variables from a user, you have to use & in front of your variables,
    select * from emp where job=&job and sal=&sal;

But pay attention to use correct format in the time that you input values, I mean 
for example, if you want to use varchar, you have to use your value between ' ' (between two single quotes)

But if you want to use input variables from a procedure and use them in your code you have to use such below simple code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE emp_name (id IN NUMBER, emp_name OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT first_name INTO emp_name
FROM emp_tbl WHERE empID = id;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i dont want to use PL/SQL